# Trying to change the routing in my MVC 5 application

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-5

When I started this site I didn't think too far a head and forgot to add product category to my data model. As it stands now when I click Products it shows the Index view which displays all the necklaces. with a path like so /Products/Index.

Now what I'm trying to do is change the routing so Index shows a list of categories then when you click, say Necklaces, I want a path like so /Products/Necklaces/Index, and so forth for all categories. Can I add folders inside my Products folder (where my views are at), or how can I go about changing the routing to account for this change?

I tried this in the **RouteConfig.cs** file

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Products",
       url: "{controller}/{category}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Products", category = "Necklaces", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

);

But **/Products/Necklaces/Index** still gives me a 404 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways you can tackle this issue.

You can add this following to your RouteConfig.cs like you did before.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Products",
    url: "{controller}/{category}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

OR

Add this to your RouteConfig.cs.

`routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

And then add this Route attribute to your Index Action.

```
// The id? means it is an optional parameter.
[Route("Products/{category}/Index/{id?}")]
public ActionResult Index(string category, string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Both of these will work.

Make sure your Action looks like that for both methods.